# How do I change the path to catalina.out?

Tags: tomcat, logging, jira

I am unable to find the setting to move the `catalina.out` logs to `/var/log/jira`.

I successfully set the path to the following files `access_log.log`,    `catalina.log`, `host-manager.log`, `localhost.log` and  `manager.log` by modifying the properties in the `conf/logging.properties` file. However I'not sure how to set the path to `catalina.out` which still gets logged in `JIRA-HOME/logs`.

The `logging.properties` had the following attributes:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I tried adding the following line:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=/var/log/jira
```

which had no impact.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I kept experimenting and discovered that there are instructions to set this in `bin/catalina.sh` which indicates that this should be set in `bin/setenv.sh` like the following:

```
CATALINA_OUT="/var/log/jira/catalina.out"
```