# How do I move Tomcat catalina.out log to a different directory

Tags: logging, tomcat7, catalina.out

I have a Tomcat7 server and I'd like to move the catalina.out log to a different directory than ${catalina.base}/logs.

1. The approach of changing CATALINA_OUT environment variable doesn't work [How do I change the path to catalina.out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194637/how-do-i-change-the-path-to-catalina-out), 
   I've modified it and I'm sure the environment variable is set to 
   CATALINA_OUT="$MY_PATH/catalina.out" before the server startup, but catalina.out stays still in ${catalina.base}/logs
2. The conf/logging.properties doesn't specify such property for catalina.out, this had been brought up in many similar discussion posts.

Is there any folks also met such problem recently or before ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194637/how-do-i-change-the-path-to-catalina-out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the path to catalina.out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194637/how-do-i-change-the-path-to-catalina-out)

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `Tomcat` Log Locations as below:

Go to: `<tomcat-base>/conf/logging.properties` and replace **<add_location_you_prefer>** with what you require;

```
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = <add_location_you_prefer>
host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
```

Lastly you will need to change the `catalina.out`:

Find the following code snippet in `Catalina.sh` script in bin directory of your tomcat base location and change the

`CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out`
to:

`CATALINA_OUT=<add_location_you_prefer>/catalina.out`